# Doubly Linked List with struct c++

Tags: c++

I have a struct named `fruit_t`:

```cpp
struct fruit_t {
    char fruit_name[MAX_LENGTH];                                            // name of fruit
    float quantity;                                                 // in lbs
    float price;                                                    // price tag of the fruit
    float new_quantity;
};

struct node_t{
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;      //constructor
    fruit_t fruit;          //data declarations
};

struct Node* head;              // global variable - pointer to head node
struct Node* create_new_Node (fruit_t fruit);
```

My question is: did I use the correct syntax for declaring `create_new_Node()`?

Comment: Instead of `struct Node*` you want `node_t*` you repeat this same typo in several places.

Comment: This looks like a C question that's tagged as C++.  Did you mean to tag it as C instead?  If you're writing C++, this is _definitely_ not the way to do it.

Comment: If you are using C++, you should use the standard `std::list` container instead of a manual implementation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see this advice a lot, but it depends on whether the task is writing a linked list or not. It's an extremely common assignment. Rarely has that advice been of benefit.

Comment: @sweenish "*It's an extremely common assignment*" - and an extremely difficult one for most beginners to get right.

Comment: Yes, and you're just dismissing them by telling them to use `std::list`. It's not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `Node` with `node_t`:

```cpp
struct node_t{
    struct node_t* next;
    struct node_t* prev;
    fruit_t fruit;
};

struct node_t* head = nullptr;
struct node_t* create_new_Node(fruit_t fruit);
```

That being said, the `struct` keyword is *optional* in C++ outside of `struct` type declarations, unlike in C where the `struct` keyword is required everywhere a `struct` is referred to.  So, the above can be shortened to this:

```cpp
struct node_t{
    node_t* next;
    node_t* prev;
    fruit_t fruit;
};

node_t* head = nullptr;
node_t* create_new_Node(fruit_t fruit);
```